# When should I think about Memory Barrier and Instruction Reorder?

Tags: c#, mutex, lock-free, memory-barriers, instruction-reordering

I tried to implement Peterson Lock with C# like this

```
public class PetersonLock
{
    private volatile bool[] flag = new bool[2];
    private volatile int victim;
    public int oneThreadId;

    public void Lock() {
        int i = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == oneThreadId ? 1 : 0;
        int j = 1 - i;
        flag[i] = true; /* A */
        victim = i;     /* B */
        while (flag[j] && victim == i) { } /* C */
    }

    public void Unlock() {
        int i = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == oneThreadId ? 1 : 0;
        flag[i] = false;
    }
}
```

But when I use this lock in 2 threads, it didn't work, someone said I should think about Instruction Reorder and use Memory Barrier. Do Line A, Line B and Line C reorder like A->B->C, or A->C->B, or C->A->B or other orders? So I changed my code to this:

```
public class PetersonLock
{
    private volatile bool[] flag = new bool[2];
    private volatile int victim;
    public int oneThreadId;

    public void Lock() {
        int i = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == oneThreadId ? 1 : 0;
        int j = 1 - i;
        flag[i] = true;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Is this line nesscessary?
        victim = i;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // Is this line nesscessary?
        while (flag[j] && victim == i) { }
    }

    public void Unlock() {
        int i = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == oneThreadId ? 1 : 0;
        flag[i] = false;
    }
}
```

- I don't know whether these two lines are both nesscessary?
- Is there any rules to help me judge which line WILL be reordered and which
  line WILL NOT be?
- When should I use Memory Barrier?

Comment: "But when I use this lock in 2 threads, it didn't work" - What do you mean by "not working"? Have you tried to use this lock in two threads, but both threads have critical section entering at the same time? Or what? Please, show the code of your "test".

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier?view=net-5.0), there are simpler ways to synchronize code using locks and the Monitor class.
If you still want to stick to `Thread.MemoryBarrier`, I found this [link](https://afana.me/archive/2015/07/10/memory-barriers-in-dot-net.aspx/) quite interesting.

Regarding your code, I'm not very familiar with the PetersonLock, so don't take my words blindly. I would say that the first barrier is used to ensure that flag is set before the victim is set and the second barrier is needed to flush the memory to all cached memory lines so all the threads read the same value

Comment: thanks. Actually I test this lock a billion times, if i didn't use any memory barrier, lock failed; if i only add the first barrier, lock also failed; however if I ONLY add the second barrier or BOTH barrier, the lock works!

Comment: Maybe your algorithm does not require the flag activation before the victim reservation. In that case the first barrier would not be needed and the second barrier would be enough to ensure the victim and the flag are updated in all cache segments before the loop starts. I'm trying to imagine a possible race condition that would happen if the victim is set before the flag but nothing comes to my mind right now.

Comment: @WardenAllen: Keep in mind that a test which doesn't find a problem doesn't *prove* correctness of the source wrt. portable language standards, especially in multi-threading.   It's good evidence that the machine code which eventually ran is probably safe on that machine, but that's all.  Testing on x86-64 means that only compile-time reordering matters for a lot of things https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/ (except StoreLoad reordering / store-forwarding which is actually relevant for Peterson locking; it does need to block StoreLoad reordering at some point.)